# soDumpMe: a Ruby script co convert Data Dump XML to HTML

Tags: app, ruby, data-dump

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

Screenshot coming soon!

### About

This app was created to solve [a request on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/128451/data-dump-of-closed-beta-sites/128457) that the XML of the data dump is not readable. This app aims to convert the XML to HTML.

**This needs a *lot* of work to be useful!** As more development is done I will update this question. **If this app would be useful to you, let me know!** I have a lot of things on my plate and I try to spend my time on the projects which are most wanted by the community.

To use, run it in a terminal and pass the path of a data dump folder. The script will output HTML to the console:

```
[jnet@Kyle Scratch]$ ./soDumpMe.rb ~/Downloads/012012\ Sexuality/012012\ Sexuality  > "012012 Sexuality.html"
```

The HTML that is produced groups Questions with their Answers and shows scores. Nothing more... yet. **Stay tuned for updates!**

#### License

Unicorn Software License / MIT license

**Anyone is free to take my crappy code and improve it!**

#### Download

[Source available from my website](http://josh.gitlin.name/software/soDumpMe.rb). I'll make a Git / SVN repo for this soon.

#### Platform

Script is written in Ruby so it should run on any platform which can run Ruby.

### Contact

You can contact me here on Stack Apps, or on [Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/131541/the-unhandled-exception). You can also email me at: `soDumpMe -at- josh -dot- gitlin -dot- name`

### Code

This app was written in Ruby and requires the **xmlsimple** RubyGem: `gem install xmlsimple`

Comment: So this produces a single page with all of the questions and answers?

Comment: @GeorgeEdison for now, yes. It's pretty limited, but it can be expanded to produce a page with a list of links to all questions, each in their own page, as the site works. Just depends on how much interest there is, how much time I have, and hoe much (if at all) help I get :-)

Comment: @Josh Github and people will help.

Comment: I'd offer to help except I know nothing about Ruby :(

Comment: FWIW, I have a set of tools that can do the same thing with an XML data dump: https://github.com/ghewgill/so-static (there's not much documentation, but enough to make it go)

Comment: Ah, finally found the original post: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/20823/stack-overflow-portable-edition

Comment: @GregHewgill Awesome! Maybe I should be improving those instead! I'll check those out when I get a chance.